# How to quickly Comment and uncomment a code?

Tags: visual-studio

Sometimes I have the need to try: A code example or a variant of it.
    This is necessary to test a new functionality or to test its implementation or performance.
    The code can be very long.
So I need some way to quickly comment on the code with

```
/*  
 * mi código  
 * …  
 * /
```

O con:

```
//  
// mi código  
// …  
//
```

When the code is very long, it is cumbersome to do: Select all the code you do not want to run and discuss, Write or insert the code you want to try, Do tests or whatever...
Now...
  Select and comment on the new block of code.
  Search and select the previous code, and Uncomment.
  Do tests or whatever...
And so I need to do it many times since I'm recycling, as I have been thirty years since I program almost nothing.

Is There any way or trick to do it quickly?

Comment: This is not a question. Should it be one?

Comment: Reformulated as a question and added as an answer. Espèro have done well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're in vs code just enter ctrl + /. For VS studio 2017 ctrl + k + u.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer!
But I didn't quite see the relationship.
Do you really realize that you must first select all the lines to be commented?
Using the method described, you do not need to select anything to toggle behavior. Just remove or put a "/" and the commented text will alternate from commented to uncommented and back again.
It is necessary to carry that there can be no comments of the type /* ... */ since they prevent its operation.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using visual studio as your IDE you can use the following:
`Ctrl+K+C` to commment and `Ctrl+K+U` to uncomment.

If using pycharm or VS Code:
Use `Cntrl+/` to comment and uncomment.

Answer (score 7):

In Visual Studio 2019 Preview

Comment : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

Uncomment : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

1. You can select all lines in the code cell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Mac)
2. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (Mac) to uncomment
3. Press <kbd>/</kbd> again to comment

Answer (score 1):

if u want comment in VS code select the entire line of comment which you want
and click on **ctrl+ / **
It is used for all types of languages

Answer (score -1):

**Trick:**
When We have a very long code and need to comment and uncomment quickly:
ADD at the beginning of the BLOCK:

```
/*//TODO: Comment or uncomment this block.
```

Remove an inclined bar at the beginning of the line to uncomment.
   Add an inclined bar at the beginning of the line to comment. '
And add at the end of the block

```
/*/
```

The tag TODO: It shows you in tasks the message,
so you can locate it quickly.
In Addition the commented code can collapse in the [+] when it is commented.

Commented Code:

```
[+]/*//TODO: Add a  "/" at startup to uncomment.
      This block does something.
       ...
       Code 100000.0 lines.
       ...
   /*/
```

Uncommented Code:

```
   //*//TODO: Remove a  "/" at startup to comment.
      This block does something.
[+]    ...
       Code 100000.0 lines.
       ...
/*/
```

I Didn't know how to tell everybody, like I do.
I Hope it's useful.

Comment: Do you comment all your lines with a TODO ?

Comment: Yes I do. Comment and uncomment all lines.